# Is it possible to have X and Y axes if a chart in C# to be on the same scale?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I have an array with some values it it. I want to display it as a scatter plot using Chart in C#.

The values will always be between 0 and 1.

The X axis takes the index of the array, but I need it to have the same as the values to be displayed.

**This is what I am getting.**

[image: Chart with X Axis giving Entries]

**This is what I am expecting.**

[image: Expected Graph]

How can I accomplish this?

I am using the following code to accomplish this:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(myArray[k]);
```

I tried using the following options, but didn't help.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0.2;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add them using AddXY(double, double), then it will work:

```
double[] myArray = { 12, 13, 5, 2 };
foreach (double val in myArray)
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(val, val);
}
```

Comment: It is just an array of doubles.